# Write a function to reduce duplicate code

Tags: python, django

I have two very similar for loops, I want to have an inner function to reduce the duplicate codes, they look like this:

```
team_members = TeamMember.objects.all()
managers = Manager.objects.all()
for m in managers:
        name = f"{m.name.first_name} {m.name.last_name}"
//reset of the code are the same
for t in team_members:
        name = f"{t.member.first_name} {t.member.last_name}"
//reset of the code are the same
```

So the problem is managers and team_members querysets have different field names for people's names.
If I want to write an inner function, how to solve the different field names?

Comment: Keep the names as strings, and use `getattr` and `setattr` to access them.

Comment: This combined with Shreeyansh Jain's code solved my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the inner function which will take objs as input and fetch the values based on objects attribute.

```
def inner_fun(objs):
    for obj in objs:
        if hasattr(obj, 'name'):
            name_obj = getattr(obj, 'name')
        else:
            name = getattr(obj, 'member')
        name = f"{name_obj.first_name} {name_obj.last_name}"
    return name

team_members = TeamMember.objects.all()
managers = Manager.objects.all()

team_name = inner_fun(team_members)
manager_name = inner_fun(managers)
```

Comment: I finally used this solution cause it fits the unshown codes the best, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could pass in `m.name` and `t.member` to that function which would allow it to access that item.

```py
for m in managers:
    func(m.name)
for t in team_members:
    func(t.member)

def func(member):
    name = f'{member.first_name} {member.last_name}
    #Rest of code
```

Comment: I didn't put the return because the rest of the code is in the function, which wouldn't need the return. Also, this is just to show the general idea

Comment: I prefer this solution. It's simpler.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tom Karzes solution in code:

```py
team_members = TeamMember.objects.all()
managers = Manager.objects.all()
    
for group, attr_name in zip([team_members, managers], ['name', 'member']):
    for person in group:
        name = f"{getattr(person, attr_name).first_name} {getattr(person, attr_name).last_name}"
```